# How to attach a .gpx file to a mail sent with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, mime-types

I am trying to attach a .gpx file into a mail sent using Google Apps Script.

The gpx file is located into my DriveApp root folder.

The problem is that I cannot find a MIME type for gpx files when creating the blob.

I don't know if it is possible to set custom MIME types ?

How can I attach a gpx file to a mail sent using Google Apps Script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, how about giving the mimeType of gpx to the blob? I think that there might be several methods for this situation. So please think of these as two of them.

#### Sample script 1:

```
var id = "### fileId of gpx file ###";
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob();
blob.setContentTypeFromExtension();

Logger.log(blob.getContentType()) // application/gpx+xml
```

In this sample script, at first, it retrieves the blob of gpx file. Then, it gives the mimeType of gpx using `setContentTypeFromExtension()`. The mimeType of blob becomes `application/gpx+xml`. By this, you can send an email including the blob with `application/gpx+xml`.

#### Sample script 2:

```
var id = "### fileId of gpx file ###";
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob();
blob.setContentType("application/gpx+xml");

Logger.log(blob.getContentType()) // application/gpx+xml
```

In this sample script, it gives the mimeType of gpx using `setContentType()`.

#### Note:

- The sample script 1 supposes that the extension of file name is `.gpx`. Because `setContentTypeFromExtension()` sets the mimeType using the extension of file name. If the gps file has no extension, please use the sample script 2.

#### Reference:

- [setContentTypeFromExtension()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setContentTypeFromExtension())
- [setContentType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setcontenttypecontenttype)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.